# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_setenv()

Tags: php, php-8.2

Recently I upgraded Debian Version 11.8 to 12.4 ( bullseye -> bookworm )
This included also an upgrade of php 7.3 to 8.2
After the upgrade almost all web services were running but only one didn't. In the logs I found that the call "apache_setenv()" did rise the issue. To narrow down the issue I created a new VS with a single file "_index3.php" and this content.

```
<html>
<head><title>PHP Test Page</title></head>
<body>
     <p>Hello World </p>

     <p>setenv </p>
     <?php
     apache_setenv("EXAMPLE_VAR", "Example Value");
                
     $ret = getenv("EXAMPLE_VAR");
     echo $ret;
     ?>
     <p>end of setenv </p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open a browser to this server and file I get this error in the apache error logfile.

```
[Wed Jan 31 17:47:30.558825 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2445535] [client 192.168.241.29:51814] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_setenv() in /opt/testserver.home.yer.at/docs/_index3.php:8\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /opt/testserver.home.yer.at/docs/_index3.php on line 8'
```

Based on PHP documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php the apache_setenv() call should be available also in version 8.

Any ideas what could cause this error and how to fix it ?

Comment: check if your php is running as module, apache_setenv() does not work if php is running as fpm. you can also check in php.ini if apache_setenv is in disabled_functions (but it is more likely because php is not running as a module)

Comment: the Server API  is FPM/FastCGI. OK, therefore it will not work. I don't see the reason why this question is closed, because the solution for "apache_setenv" and "apache_getenv" is not the same. 
When I run "apache2ctl -M" I see beside several others

Comment: "a2query -m" shows 
`env (enabled by maintainer script)
mpm_prefork (enabled by maintainer script)
php8.2 (enabled by maintainer script)
proxy_fcgi (enabled by site administrator)
setenvif (enabled by maintainer script)
`
It seems that the php module is loaded but not used as Apache is running in wrong mode.  Is there a way to change this mode ? 

Or is there a workaround for apache_setenv() ?